# Polymorphism of parameter of ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to know if it is possible to convert controller's post action parameter from one type to another. I have tried to use code but it does not work:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(object parameter)
{
    var parsed = parameter as TestViewModel;
    //always get null here, even if view's model is TestViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view's model is not what's used as a parameter to your Action method unless you specify for that model to be used like so:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Test(TestViewModel parameter)
 {
     //model binding will attempt to set the properties 
     //on `parameter object` based on the values posed back.
 }
```